# variance and autocorrelation function of a time series function

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, variance, time-series

Suppose that $ \varepsilon_t$ is an i.i.d WN(0,1) process, that

$\alpha_t=\varepsilon_t\sqrt{1+0.35\alpha_{t-1}^2} \quad$,

$\mathcal{y{_t}}= 3+ 0.72\mathcal{y{_{t-1}}}+\alpha_t$

(a) Find the mean of $\mathcal{y{_t}}$

(b) Find the variance of $\mathcal{y{_t}}$

(c) Find the autocorrelation function of $\alpha_t^2$

I was able to get (a). Since the expectation of $\alpha_t$ is always 0 so I have:
$E{[\mathcal{y{_t}}]} = \frac{3}{1-0.72}$. I'm not too sure how to proceed with (b) and (c).

Comment: Did you mean $\alpha_t = \varepsilon_t \sqrt{1+0.35^2\alpha_{t-1}^{\color{red}2}}$? Otherwise you may get in trouble with negative values. Also because in that case $\alpha_t$ is an $\operatorname{ARCH}(1)$ process and your equations define an [$\operatorname{AR}(1)\operatorname{-ARCH}(1)$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/204644/proper-definition-of-ar-arch-time-series-model) model.

Comment: @Therkel yes you are correct, I have edited the question to reflect the change.